# Chrome store always install old version of ARC Welder

Tags: google-chrome-arc

No matter what I do, using windows vista, seven and 8.1, both 32-bit & 64-bit, I always end getting version 288 from chrome store instead of the newest. Problem is, this version does not work on 32-bit windows (works fine on 64-bit). I can see lots and lots of posts on the store about the same issue.

Question is, how to get and updated version?

Answer (score 0):

ARC Welder as well as the ARC Runtime are both strongly tied to the version of Chrome you are running.

ARC Welder 288 (currently 42.4410.288.35) is what you get if you have any version of Chrome that begins with 42, such as 42.0.2311.153 which is what is currently released for Chromebooks. It is our stable release to match the stable version of Chrome.

In the time since you wrote this question, Chrome 43 has been released, so you should be on 43.4410.349.9 at least under Windows. Chromebooks should be updating to 43 sometime this week, as I understand their process.

You can only otherwise get a newer version of ARC/ARC Welder by using a beta, dev, or canary release of Chrome. However be aware that you may end up:

1. Using versions of ARC that aren't as well tested.
2. Using features of ARC that might work for you, but not if you publish your app and it is used by someone using the Stable version of Chrome/ARC runtime.

If you are still having problems with a newer version of ARC Welder, or want to help us understand the older version, please feel free to add to the [existing bug](http://crbug.com/473704). One thing we do not have yet are logs of the actual errors people are encountering.